# Android InApp Subscription Architecture

Tags: java, android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have read lot of documentation and blogs but could not find a concrete answer.

So I have an app where I need to integrate in-app weekly subscription and also have a backend server that stores user data so when the purchase is made I send data to the server that user is subscribed and update database and give the user access to the app.
I wanted to know how to handle the cases when a subscription  is cancelled or ended. How to check that in the app?
What is the best architecture look like for In-app billing and Server?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play doesn't have important documentation and even the lastest documentation for Billing 3.0 has some bugs, but if you are just looking for process and can figure out the code for yourself here is the in-app subscription architecture described by google on their official Android Developers channel on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9J8ylTbNo1mnwciEyMbxZG